# Ralink Wireless N Wifi card not working

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers, ralink

I have a wireless-N card from Ralink. On the chip I can read the number "RT3062f". I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

On a fresh Ubuntu install, the card is recognized, but does not detect any signals (which is unlikely since it sits next to the router, and all my other device connect just fine).

I tried installing the driver from the CD that came with the card but it won't compile. I also tried downloading a driver from the Ralink website, but after installing, the card won't scan at all.

Here are some links to forum threads that I thought were headed in the right direction:

[How do I get a Ralink RT3060 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84959/ralink-rt3060-driver-not-working)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908542

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1609086

**Diagnostics:**

```
morgan@mohi:~/Downloads$ iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


morgan@mohi:~/Downloads$ iwlist scanning
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results


morgan@mohi:~/Downloads$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12493  1 
isofs                  39549  1 
bnep                   17923  2 
rfcomm                 38408  0 
bluetooth             148839  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
snd_intel8x0           33318  2 
snd_ac97_codec        106082  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus               12642  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                80435  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25241  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
rt2800pci              18340  0 
rt2800lib              48909  1 rt2800pci
crc_ccitt              12595  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00pci              14202  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              48146  3 rt2800pci,rt2800lib,rt2x00pci
joydev                 17393  0 
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
mac80211              393421  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib
snd_timer              28932  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
hid_microsoft          12728  0 
cfg80211              172427  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
usbhid                 41905  0 
hid                    77367  2 hid_microsoft,usbhid
i915                  509519  3 
snd                    55902  11      snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12600  1 snd
eeprom_93cx6           12653  1 rt2800pci
drm_kms_helper         32889  1 i915
drm                   192194  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  18908  1 i915
ppdev                  12849  0 
psmouse                73673  0 
serio_raw              12990  0 
parport_pc             32114  1 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
tg3                   132972  0 
floppy                 60310  0
```

**If I try to compile the driver from CD:**

```
morgan@mohi:~/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0$ sudo make
make -C tools
...

/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1570:10: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘open’
/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1571:10: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘stop’
/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1572:10: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘hard_start_xmit’
/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1573:10: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘do_ioctl’
/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1579:11: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘get_stats’
/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1613:9: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘validate_addr’
make[2]: ***      [/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: ***     [_module_/home/morgan/Downloads/2009_0521_RT2860_Linux_STA_V2.1.2.0/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

**After installing driver from website**

```
morgan@mohi:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

ra0       Ralink STA  
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0



morgan@mohi:~$ iwlist scanning
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

ra0       Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Try my process[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/a/925005/642288), hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, yes, you do need to install the driver from Ralink to get that card working. But a much newer version is available. I am using version 4.1.1. I recommend that you find and download that version. It should be available from Ralinktech website.

Once you get the driver, expand it into its own directory. From that directory, run "sudo make", then "sudo make install". Then run "sudo modprobe rt3562sta". Your wireless should come up in a few seconds.

It is also a good idea to blacklist the default module, rt2800pci.

Also, you will have to reinstall this driver after each time the Linux kernel is upgraded to a higher version.

Comment: Hrm. No luck. I installed the driver, ran modprobe. Same result as above. The card is now recognized as ra0 and isn't recognized as a wireless device apparently.

Perhaps I downloaded the wrong driver? There doesn't seem to be any identifying information on the box. Just that number RT3062f on the chip.

I grabbed the driver labeled "RT3062PCI/mPCI/CB/PCIe(RT3060/RT3062/RT3562/RT3592) 12/17/2010 2.4.1.1" from the Ralink website.

Comment: OK, looks like this would eventually work. I got a script from this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1608095&page=14. After a few tries, it finally worked. Thanks for the help!