# Ralink RT5360 Wireless not working

Tags: ralink

I have built myself a new server/pc. I happened to installed a WiFi card that was not supported by ubuntu 12.04 lts, so I found drivers that worked and all was good for some time. After the kernel update I rebuilt the drivers with no success, so I ran the live CD of 13.04 and the WiFi worked cool. I then did the upgrade to 12.10 and finely to 13.04 but the WiFi is still not working. Any suggestions?

```
lspci

Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R


sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
vendor: Ralink corp.
physical id: 6
bus info: pci@0000:03:06.0
version: 00
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
resources: memory:fd3f0000-fd3fffff
```

Comment: Does it start working if you open a terminal and do: sudo modprobe rt2800pci  If so, we can make it permanent. If not, check the logs for error messages: dmesg | grep rt2

Comment: thanks chili555. sudo modprobe rt2800pci worked, how can we make it permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo su
echo rt2800pci >> /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set but feel free to post back if you need additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu has been facing issues with Ralink wireless drivers from 12.04. I have also faced that issue in Ralink RT3290 after switching from Unity to GDM (Ubuntu 16.04)

One easy and quick solution is

1. Delete /etc/Wireless (using `sudo rm -rf /etc/Wireless`)
2. Use your live USB (bootable Ubuntu) and boot from it, and "Try Ubuntu" in boot option.
3. In my case after booting live USB, I have connected the internet using USB tethering from my mobile device which is optional that I don't think should make any difference.

Also add

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial main
http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial main (Source code)
```

in Other Software of Software & Update and check them.

took hardly 5 minutes to execute.
Kind of illogical but worked.

Worked well for me!

Tell me if it worked.

Comment: I don't see a Wireless directory in /etc, though I don't have a Ralink card and I'm using Unity.

Comment: @wjandrea this thread is for Ralink wireless hardware.I can afford only one laptop to explore my hardware knowledge. Had to be saved somewhere in /etc, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Still i will explore for other hardware and guide you through it

Comment: Following my procedure will lead to restore basic driver of Ralink wireless i.e. Rt 2860/Rt2870, which had been compatible to most of the wireless hardware manufactured my Ralink.