# D-Link DWA 525 Wifi Adapter Installation Error

Tags: wireless, networking

Until a week ago, I was on Ubuntu (laptop). I just sold my laptop and picked up a desktop. I never realised the Internet issue until I installed Ubuntu 13.10. The system fails to connect to the Internet.

It surely recognises the presence of the adapter because it clearly asks for the password. I have only wifi at home and no wired connection. I researched a lot of questions here as well as in Ubuntu Forums, but sadly no answer helped, mainly because they are all old. Realised it's a driver issue.

I need to get back to Ubuntu to practice Python programming. Windows giving too many problems. Plus, I am a Linux newbie, so can't hack my way into this.

Can anyone help me configure the wifi adapter and get me online?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the output of `lshw -c network` to your question.

Comment: This is what I see - description: Wireless interface
       product: RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 6
       bus info: pci@0000:04:06.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: c8:be:19:04:5d:3e
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: What about `configuration: driver=???` ?

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310261/ralink-rt5360-wireless-not-working) work? - it is a similar question. Also what does `sudo rfkill list` produce?

Comment: I installed ubuntu last night but now unable to boot. It comes to grub shows options, but keyboard won't work. What do I do?

Comment: Does the keyboard light up (do Num Lock or Caps lock lights work?). Try another keyboard. If it is a USB keyboard, you may want to try a PS/2 one as it may be the USB ports - also vice-versa. When you get it working, you could always try another release, e.g. 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply re-installed the OS and it worked. The Internet is working fine. Detected by default. No drivers, nothing. As for the keyboard, I removed it from the port and connected it to the USB port that was part of the Motherboard. You will find it on top of the CPU. It worked!

All this on Ubuntu 13.10. Thanks everyone who tried to help.