# Ralink RT3060 wireless device configuration on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, ralink

concerning [How do I get a Ralink RT3060 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84959/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3060-wireless-card-working/)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with a 'LWPX07 Edimax EW-7711In 150M 1T1R WL PCI Card' which has a rt3060 chip. Out of the box the card is recognized as rt2800sta. I tried solution one, that didn't work. Still the card connects to the wireless network, but it seems to slow to load any pages.

Then I tried solution 2, but then the network-manager doesn't see any wireless device.

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
ra0       Ralink STA  
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0
eth0      no wireless extensions.

$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rt3562sta             882296  0

$ lspci -v
05:02.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
    Subsystem: Edimax Computer Co. Device 7711
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 23
    Memory at ff9f0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2860
    Kernel modules: rt3562sta, rt2800pci
```

Am I missing a configuration step? How do I tell the network card which driver to use?

Comment: Can you please answer your own question with that? Thanks

Comment: Don't use sudo su, use sudo -s Or much more appropriate for your commands, make && sudo make install make doesn't need admin priviledge, but install does.

Answer (score 2):

[Stephan solved the problem in his question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/199273/2):

> I found the problem. As described in stevens blog http://steveswinsburg.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-a-d-link-dwa-525-wireless-network-card-in-ubuntu-10-04/
>
> ```
> sudo su
> make && make install
> ```
>
> "You need to use sudo su and not just sudo so it creates the directories properly." That is the problem with the solution describe above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as luck would have it, I am using the exact one on a Raspberry Pi. I also tested the Wireless device on 13.04 and after ~2 minutes, the connection dropped. It was detected but not working on 12.04 and 12.10, so I have to grab the drivers from the official site and compile them.

Here are the steps similar to the [Official Edimax GOfficial Edimax guide for Ubuntuuide for Ubuntu](http://www.edimax.co.uk/images/Image/FAQ/Wireless/Linux/How%20to%20install%20EW-7711xxx%20_3070_%20on%20Linux%20Ubuntu%2010.4%20platform.pdf):

1. Go to the [Edimax Site](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=326&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44)
2. Download the [Latest Drivers](http://www.edimax.co.uk/images/Image/Driver_Utility/Wireless/NIC/EW-7711IN/EW-7711IN_2010_07_16_RT3062_Linux_STA_v2%5B1%5D.4.0.0.tar.bz2.zip)
3. Extract the downloaded file (You need to extract the file 2 times. the first because of the ZIP format, the other is for the tar.gz) and open the newly created folder. The folder should be called **2010_07_16_RT3062_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0**. I recommend extracting the folder in your Desktop folder or home folder so it is easier to get to. Then go to the terminal and type the following (Assuming it is on the desktop):

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/2010_07_16_RT3062_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0
   ```
4. Blacklist the default module for this Wireless Driver (This way, when you use the new driver module it works without creating a problem with the older one):

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```

   Add at the bottom of the file the following line:

   ```
   blacklist rt2800usb  
   blacklist rt2800pci
   ```

   And save the file.
5. Now go to `2010_07_16_RT3062_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0/os/linux/` and edit the file **config.mk**

   Change the following variables:

   ```
   HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
   ```

   and save the file.

   NOTE: When opening the `config.mk` file, do not only change the **HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT** to a value of `y`, but also do it with **HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT** in case it has `n`. In my case it had `y` but it should be checked to make sure both **WPA_SUPPLICANT** are set to `y`.
6. Go to your main extracted folder (It should be the `2010_07_16_RT3062_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.0` folder) and type the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
   make      
   sudo make install
   ```
7. If everything compiled correctly do the following:

   ```
   modprobe rt3562sta
   ```
8. If step 7 runs without any problems, we add the module to the list of modules to loaded upon every boot:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modules
   ```

   and add a line at the end of the file that says **rt3562sta**.

   Save and exit. I recommend rebooting to see and check the device.