# How do I install RALink 3290?

Tags: wireless, ralink

I have been trying for awhile since I removed Win8 from my laptop to get this Bluetooth/Wireless Card working and I've got it so that it at least recognizes wireless, but every time I try to actually use the wireless, I get kernel panics or everything crashes.

Can someone explain to me how to install this driver: 
http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501

So that I can actually use the wireless on my laptop (and perhaps even the bluetooth).

Comment: Get info here, see for 12.04 [How do I get a Ralink RT3060 wireless card working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84959/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3060-wireless-card-working)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've solved this. I have the HP Envy dv7 and seem to have it working.

Ubuntu 12.10 - no wireless detected.
upgrade the linux kernel to 3.6.3 or later and make sure the firmware rt3290.bin is in lib/firmware and it should work.

However I have found that sometimes the wireless is disabled and the only way I have found to re-enable it is to boot into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the ralink site has changed... I don't know where to find the new files on the new serv, so here's the instruction how to get it working using the kernel firmware:

[How do I install ra3290.bin wireless driver into /lib/firmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240553/how-do-i-install-ra3290-bin-wireless-driver-into-lib-firmware)

It's a simple 2-line instruction. Works under hp 4540s, ralink 3290.