# How do I install ra3290.bin wireless driver into /lib/firmware

Tags: wireless, ralink

I have a HP ENVY dv7 that has the rt3290 wireless card.  A dude answered a [question on installing the rt3290 wireless driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226381/how-do-i-install-ralink-3290) suggested upgrading the kernel to above 3.6.3, he then also said to make sure that you have the rt3290.bin file in the /lib/firmware/ directory.

How do you obtain this rt3290.bin file? How do you upgrade the firmware?

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/rt3290.bin /lib/firmware
```

It works immediately after the above command execution.

My notebook is Fujitsu Lifebook LH532
Ralink RT3290
Running kernel 3.8.0.2 in Ubuntu 13.04
as 1st FEB 2013

Comment: This stopped working after I rebooted.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is temporary workaround:

Install kernell 3.6.x from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline

```
linux-headers-3.6.6-030606-generic_3.6.6-030606.201211050512_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.6.6-030606_3.6.6-030606.201211050512_all.deb
linux-image-3.6.6-030606-generic_3.6.6-030606.201211050512_amd64.deb
linux-image-extra-3.6.6-030606-generic_3.6.6-030606.201211050512_amd64.deb
```

You can use USC to install the DEB. Then download the firmware from kernel.org and copy it to `/lib/firmware`:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/rt3290.bin /lib/firmware
```

and reboot.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466/comments/8) and [Reply 16 confirms it works](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466/comments/16).

Comment: This only worked for me until I rebooted.  Any pointers?