# How to set up D-LINK DWA-111 USB WLAN Adapter?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb, ralink

I today got stuck while trying to install/set up my USB-WLAN Adapter.
It's a DWA-111 USB-Stick (Rev. A1) and my machine is currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. (As far as I know it's got a RT73 chipset by ralink, but I am not completely sure.)
So much for this.

The Adapter runs perfectly using a machine with Win7 installed but it does absolutely nothing when I plug it at my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.
`iwconfig` and `ifconfig` show nothing, as well as the device is not listed when executing `lsusb`. So it seems it's entirely unknown to my computer.

Here's some output of `lsusb`, now showing the D-LINK device (as already described below in comments I just noticed the device is appearing and disappearing every now and then):

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 07cc:0301 Carry Computer Eng., Co., Ltd 6-in-1 Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 046d:c223 Logitech, Inc. Keyboard / USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1e7d:2ced Logitech Mouse
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 046d:c226 Logitech, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 046d:c227 Logitech, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 039: ID 07d1:3c06 D-Link System
```

Information on an error in `/var/log/syslog`

```
May  5 18:34:39 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7738.978659] phy1 -> rt73usb_init_eeprom: Error - Invalid RT chipset detected.
May  5 18:34:39 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7738.978662] phy1 -> rt2x00lib_probe_dev: Error - Failed to allocate device.
May  5 18:34:39 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7738.978763] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 12
May  5 18:34:39 COMPUTER mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 12 was not an MTP device
May  5 18:34:39 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7739.092048] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
May  5 18:34:40 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7739.258536] usb 1-9: too many configurations: 60, using maximum allowed: 8
May  5 18:34:40 COMPUTER mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-9"
May  5 18:34:40 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7739.796047] usb 1-9: reset high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
May  5 18:34:40 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7739.962505] usb 1-9: device firmware changed
May  5 18:34:40 COMPUTER kernel: [ 7739.962547] phy2 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x09 failed for offset 0x0000 with error -19.
```

This error messages just keep repeating over and over.

Any ideas how do I get the device installed and running? And additionally any idea about the `lsusb` behaviour?
Thank you!

Comment: `lsusb` has to list it anyway, try `lsusb -v`. Sometimes the vendor name differs from that is shown in windows. Check the IDs.

Comment: OK, just experienced a very weird behaviour of `lsusb` I just ran it several times and the 4th time I executed it, it showed the D-LINK device. But then, running `lsusb` a 5th time is disappeared again. (I'll add the output of `lsusb` above.)

Comment: The disappearing device can be a power management thing, but still, it shouldn't disappear from the device list completely. Look for traces about that in the `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/dmesg`, and `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`. The kernel driver for this device is the `rt73usb` module, load it with `sudo modprobe rt73usb`. Also make sure that the `linux-firmware` package is installed.

Comment: Thank you @grimpitch . I found some information about the error in `/var/log/syslog`. I will soon add the output above as well.

Comment: I suspect the device is failing.

Comment: Which, of course is not completely impossible but would be a bit strange if it runs perfectly fine using a machine running Win7. Is there any way to clarify this point? (I will try to test the stick on some other computers tomorrow.)

Answer (score 1):

USB ID: **07d1:3c06**

D-Link Systems **DWA-111 802.11bg Wireless Adapter** - [Ralink **RT2571W**]

Source: [Debian.org > Ralink RT2501USB/RT2571W (RT73) devices](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/rt73)

---

Possible solutions:

(1.) [How do I get a Ralink RT3060 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84959/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3060-wireless-card-working) (for 12.04)

> **Option 1.** Try installing the latest compat-wireless backports package
>   and see if it works ..
>
> **Option 2.** Build and install Ralink's own drivers ..

(2.) Load the device-firmware drivers (to load firmware to device)

**`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`**

Comment: well, I tried all these steps but none works. Which also would lead to the conclusion that the device is broken - but as I tested it one more time on a Windows 7 machine and it worked I can say, that it's fully functional there. Just keeps disappearing again and again on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Look at other **RaLink** issues on this forum. Click on that tag (below your question).