# Driver for Ralink corp. Device 3020

Tags: wireless, ralink, additional-drivers

I would like to get the Driver software for below mentioned Wireless card.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
04:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3020]
```

It was working previously and I lost it along the way of OS upgrade.

Comment: Ive found this post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) that maybe can provide you some information

Comment: @kek_kek, thanks for your reply. My wireless card belongs to Ralink 3020,  the link you have given has a different version. Anyway, I will see if there are any clue for me.

Comment: Go to http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/rt8070-rt3070-rt3370-rt3572-rt5370-rt5372-rt5572-usb-usb/, inform your name, e-mail address and captcha code, then click **Submit**. You'll get a download link. Download the tarball (**.tar.bz2** file) and extract it to some folder. There will be a README file with compilation instructions. It does have the driver you seek, because under the folder **chips** there's a C-language file named **rt30xx.c** with several instances of the word **RT3020** in it. But I'm not sure if it will work with the Linux kernel of your current system.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, make certain it's not now listed in the blacklists found in /etc/modprobe.d/  If it shows in any of those blacklists then 
`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-[file name it's blacklisted in]` and add a # at the start of the line which lists it (It's extremely unlikely that it would now be blacklisted if it was not previously).
If not in one of the blacklists or adding the "#" in front of it did not bring it back online (a reboot is usually a good idea after such a hardware change) then try `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` 
If that does not solve the problem then please provide the output of `lspci-v`
You might also make certain that the "linux-firmware" package is installed  as it includes many drivers.  If you still wish to download the driver then you can do so directly from ralink's driver webpage: http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/

Hope this helps find your answer.

Respectfully,
David

Comment: David, thanks for your reply. Essentially I followed the instruction #2 on http://askubuntu.com/a/175399/52683 but leaves me with the following error http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/20295521/ on issuing make command. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/20295875/ has more info about my system in this context. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use sudo in front of the make command in terminal.  You need to be the system administrator (Consider sudo to mean "Super User Do Once").  For all steps in such an install for hardware you want to add sudo as the first item in the line (if sudo isn't needed it would have any negative effect unless you request something which would damage part of the system). Should solve your new issue. If you want to download the Linux driver from Mediatek (Ralink's maker) here is the link http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/rt8070-rt3070-rt3370-rt3572-rt5370-rt5372-rt5572-usb-usb/

Comment: No luck. Getting error on running make command. See http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/20330921/.

Comment: Sudo is not in your pastbin file. That suggests you may have forgotten to enter it.

Comment: I just downloaded the driver file from Realtek myself and after cd /[download location]/  then sudo make it installed with no problem whatsoever.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-1lAPlHMTDgOHlJckVoVlZlLTQ

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were working with a Ralink device, not a Realtek, but the outcome due to "sudo make" rather than "make" should be the same. I downloaded the PCI NIC driver from Ralink and the file is misformatted and unrecoverable. Unless they correct their mistake you would have to download it elsewhere to be able to unzip and install it. But Sudo make is the manner to make such an installation. You should also try to use Ubuntu's Additional Drivers tab in the software sources to ensure there is no driver presented there